# Split hive partition to create multiple partition

Tags: hive, bigdata, partition

I have an external hive table which is partitioned on load_date (DD-MM-YYYY). however the very first period lets say 01-01-2000 has all the data from 1980 till 2000. How can I further create partitions on year for the previous data while keeping the existing data (data for load date greater than 01-01-2000) still available

Comment: Can you make the question clearer please. Am I right in assuming that you have one partition to hold all data on or prior to 2000; you have daily partitions from 2001 onwards? Then what are you trying to load. A concrete example would help us answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

First load the data of '01-01-2000' into a table and create a dynamic partition table partitioned by data '01-01-2000'. This might solve your problem.

Comment: Actually It won't I still want to see all other partitions. The problem statement can be put like this, External table is partitioned on Load date coloumn and needs to be partitions on data date col. How do we do that?